# jQuery: val() updated too late

Tags: jquery, field

UPDATE: there was a problem with some other code.

I'm trying to get the value of some input text field. The problem is that the value I obtain by

```
my_val = $('#MyInput').val();
```

is not really updated.

If I write in the field 'foo' and then click on the element which triggers the script, then I get my_val = undefined.

On the other hand, if I write in the field 'foo', CLICK SOMEWHERE ELSE, and then click on the element which triggers the script, then I get my_val = 'foo'.

It looks like Firefox updates val only on blur. Is there a way to get the correct value? (No, $('#MyInput').blur() does not work).

EDIT: I add more info as requested. I'm currently using Firefox 3.5 on Ubuntu 9.10, but the same happens on the latest beta of Chrome.

The simplest example is

```
<p>Bar</p>
<form>
<input type="text" id="input" />
</form>
```

and then a Javascript of

```
$('p').click(function() {
    my_val = $('#input').val();
    alert(my_val);
});
```

Try writing something in the input and then clicking on the paragraph without leaving the field.

EDIT2: never mind, it was some other code that was interfering. Sorry for wasting your time :-(

Comment: It works just fine for me ... (any particular browser this fails ?)

please provide more info (code) about this..

Comment: What event handler is your code running in?

Comment: So apparently it is possible to click in the <p> and not fire blur() on the input.  In any case, use .keyup() as in my answer and it will update.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `.keyup()` event handler on your input to change your variable each time the contents change:

```
var my_val;

$('#MyInput').keyup(function() {
    my_val = $(this).val();
});

$('p').click(function() {
    alert(my_val);
});
```

Note that `.change()` won't work since it too only fires on blur.

Answer (score 0):

Calling jQuery's `blur` and `focus` methods will call all event handlers that registered for the event, but won't actually change the focus.

You need to manually focus a different element, like this:

```
document.getElementById('something').focus();
```

If you do this using jQuery, you'll need to write `[0]` so that you call the DOM `focus` method, not the jQuery `focus` method.
For example:

```
$('input')[0].focus();
```

Comment: I believe `focus` and `blur` do trigger those events as long as they're not part of an event handler. see http://api.jquery.com/focus/ . I have such a script working, actually.

Comment: Uhm... I was hoping that would work but this is not the case. With that I am able to blur the field, or give focus to another, but nevertheless my_val is still undefined. :-(

Comment: @carillonator: See http://docs.jquery.com/Events/focus, which explicitly says they don't.  I checked the source to see if it changed in 1.4, but I don't see any code that would change it.

Comment: @SLaks, I see what you're talking about (don't totally understand what it's saying), but I just tried this and it works as I said, putting the cursor in the input box and giving it focus:

`$('#some_link').click(function() { $('#some_input').focus(); });`

Comment: 1.4, but I had something just like it working in 1.3.2 the other day.